# Negative lookbehind before an eager quantifier

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I need to refactor some PHP annotations, I want to replace `string[]` with `array<int, string>`.

I've tried to match the appropriate annotations with this PCRE regex:

```
(?<!\$|>)\w+\[\]
```

But it doesn't work, [here's how the regex is matching](https://regex101.com/r/OOAQc5/1/):

[image: Regex 101 preview]

The two latest lines shouldn't match. Is there any way to create a working regex for this or should I use create a custom script to do this?

Comment: Add word boundary and add `->` alternative to the lookbehind, `(?<!\$|->)\b\w+\[\]`

Comment: A lookbehind has to be fixed length, so I don't think you can mix single characters with `->`

Comment: But you can put `\b` before `\w+` so it won't match partial words

Comment: Or else `(?<![$>])\b\w+\[]`

Comment: @Barmar This PCRE, not Python. See `(?<!\$|->)\b\w+\[\]` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpJF1W/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?<!\$|->)\w+\[]
```

See the [PCRE regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jpJF1W/4).

**Details**

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?<!\$|->)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `$` or `->` immediately to the left of the current location
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars.
- `\[]`  - a `[]` substring.

See [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/EY7kp):

```
$str = '/** @var string[] */
/** @return string[] */
* @param Company[]|null $companies

$icons[] = static::getIconDetailsFromLink($link);
$this->properties[] = $property;';

if (preg_match_all('/\b(?<!\$|->)\w+\[]/', $str, $matches)) {
  print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: That's a very smart way! Thank you for your help :)